# Triggering of click event on anchor tag doesn't work if have base64 code

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, base64, anchor

I am trying to trigger click event for the anchor tag whose href have base64 code for image.

But it is not working

**JavaScript code:**

```
$("#screenShotOutput").trigger("click")
```

**HTML code:**

```
<a href="base64Code" onclick="javascript:alert('hii')" download="screenshot.png">Download Screenshot</a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnbrr33t/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First `click` and then `href` Its a default behaviour check https://jsfiddle.net/bnbrr33t/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. That is actual reason for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using click method of DOM element.

```
$("#screenShotOutput")[0].click()
```

Also, the mistake was href attribute was defined first before onclick attribute definition.

Modified HTML is:

```
<a onclick="javascript:alert('hii')" href="base64Code"  download="screenshot.png">Download Screenshot</a>
```